# In drupal Panels not showing appropriate content?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, panels

I created custom view using a tpl file which shows "No records found" if the query did not result any records. This works fine while looking at the preview of a view.But when i use the same view in a panel. I dont see "No records found" Its just a blank section of a panel. Why so? and how do i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Well its way too simple than i thought. Under the "basic settings->Empty Text" of a view. Write your own TEXT/HTML/PHP/ code to show it when there are no records.

information: When there are no records to display in a view and if you are using that view in a panel,it completely ignores your custom view-****-***.tpl.php file and will end up showing a blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

Add some text in the template file, that is always shown, to be sure, that the template is used.

Then, what is your if branch, where you check if the record list is empty?

Comment: i check for the no. of rows retrieved by the view.

Comment: If no records are fetched the tpl file is not printing anything. Not even if i print something before the " print $rows" statement. It displays the text only in the preview page of the views and not in the panel.

Comment: Then your template file is not used. Is it really the SAME view?

Comment: My template file is used. It uses my tpl file when there are records to display according to the tpl file. But if there are no records, it completely ignores my tpl file and hence i cannot print "No records found". However my tpl file's "No record found" message is displayed while previewing my view.

Comment: maybe some preferences in your panel to not use the template if view is empty?